# Alternative to spider/radar chart when dealing with a skills matrix for more than 10 people

Tags: data-visualization

I have a skills-matrix with skills on 15 people (i.e. 15 observations). I would like to visualise the skills matrix and thought about a spider/radar chart. Due to the high number of people, I suspect a spider/radar chart will, however, not be very readable.

I could use a facet graph (i.e. a panel of graphs with a spider/radar chart per person), but a comparison is then maybe more difficult.

A heat map seems a bit boring to me.

Do you know any alternatives to a spider/radar chart?

Comment: "Chernoff Faces" were used for such comparisons about 20 yrs ago. Haven't use modern software implementations. (Google) Principle is that humans are good at distinguishing among faces. Implementation involves using different features of face correspond to different variables: width btw eyes, pupils left/mid/right, smile vs frown for mouth, width of mouth, height and slant of eyebrows, length of nose, size of ears, amt of hair, etc. Don't know if faces would work for 15 variables. Used 8 for my data,. Potential difficulty: different features get different emphasis by various viewers.

Comment: @BruceET, thanks for the interesting suggestion! I didn't know about this. I would have to use it in a report. Using faces is maybe too confrontational....